# How to prove that upper bound of the hitting time holds with high probability?

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices

Let $G$  be a symmetric Gaussian random matrix with iid $E[G_{ij}]=0$ and $E[G_{ij}^2]=\frac{1}{n}$, and ordering its eigenvalues $\lambda_1\le \lambda_2\le \dots \le \lambda_n$ corresponding eigenvectors $v_1,\dots, v_n$. Define $X_t=\{X^i_t\}$ is a vector on $R^n$ for time $t\ge 0$ and $X_0$ is distributed uniformly on the unit sphere. Let $h(t)= X_t\cdot v_1$.

Let $T_\epsilon:=inf_{t>0}\{h(t)\ge \epsilon\}$. Assume that
$$
h(t)\ge h(0)e^{2(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)t}\ge h(0)e^{2\delta t}
$$
where $\delta=\min\{\lambda_i-\lambda_j\}$ is the smallest gap.

I try to find the upper bound of $T_\epsilon$ with high probability $1-Ce^{-c n}$ (or something like that).

Comment: the issue here is that $h(0)$ could be much smaller than $n^{-1/2}$ with large probability; the Gaussian distribution of $h(0)$ has a peak at 0 of height $n^{1/2}$, so $h(0)$ can be close to 0 with large probability; this produces an increase of $T_\epsilon$, beyond the $n^{2/3}\log n$ bound you write down; I have tried to work that out in the answer box.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Thank you! Do you mean $P(|h(0)|<\alpha)\ge e^{-\alpha^2/2}$? I am not sure what do you mean "with probability $\alpha\sqrt{n}$"? Does it mean $P(|h(0)|<\alpha)=\alpha \sqrt{n}$?

Comment: yes: $P(|h(0)|<\alpha)=\alpha \sqrt{n}$ --- you're sampling from the peak of the gaussian, so the probability is large, not small.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Can you explain why is $P(|h(0)|<\alpha)=\alpha \sqrt{n}$ true?

Comment: this estimate holds for $\alpha\ll \sqrt n$, since$\int_{-\alpha}^\alpha (n/2\pi)^{1/2}e^{-nx^2/2}\,dx=\text{Erf}\,(\tfrac{1}{2}\alpha\sqrt{n})=\sqrt{2/\pi}\alpha\sqrt n+{\cal O}(\alpha^2)$ --- the factor $\sqrt{2/\pi}$ is irrelevant here.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I copy a answer "An easy way to see this is that $\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow n^{-0.5}}\alpha\sqrt{n}=1$ while $\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow n^{-1/2}}\mathbb P(|X|\le a)=\mathbb P(|X|\le n^{-1/2})<1$"  from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4555166/the-probability-for-inner-product-for-two-unit-sphere-uniformly-distributed-rand/4556149?noredirect=1#comment9584426_4556149

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Do you mean $\alpha<< n^{-1/2}$?

Comment: yes, I can't edit comments, apologies; for the answer below I take $\alpha<e^{-\sqrt n}$, so definitely $\ll n^{-1/2}$.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker So this one should be ok? $P(|h(0)|\ge t)\le Ce^{-cnt^2}$? I can take $t=n^{-1/4}$.

Comment: no, it does not hold, just integrate the Gaussian and you will see it fails.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Can you explain it? I just saw a proof https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4553074/can-we-get-the-concentration-inequality-of-the-inner-product-of-two-unit-vectors

Comment: correction, it holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this upper bound holds.

Notice that the probability distribution of $h(0)$ is a Gaussian of mean 0 and width $1/\sqrt n$, so the probability that $|h(0)|<\alpha$ is $\alpha\sqrt n$ for $0<\alpha<1/\sqrt n$.

Since $\lambda_2-\lambda_1\simeq n^{-2/3}$, the hitting time $T_\epsilon$ for $h(0)=\alpha$ is
$$T_\epsilon\lesssim n^{2/3}\log(\epsilon/\alpha).$$
Choose $\alpha<e^{-\sqrt n}$, then $T_\epsilon$ can be larger than  $n^{1/2}n^{2/3}>n^{2/3}\log n$ with probability $\sqrt{n}e^{-\sqrt n}$, so a larger probability than the $e^{-n}$ conjectured in the OP.

Comment: Also, since $\sqrt{n} h(0)\to N(0, 1)$ weakly as $n\to \infty$, then $h(0)=O_p(n^{-1/2})$. Then $T_\epsilon \le C n^{2/3}\log n$ with probability 1 as $n\to \infty$. Does it make sense?

Comment: my point is that your upper bound $n^{2/3}\log n$ is too small; in the example I gave the upper bound is $n^{1/2}n^{2/3}$, which greatly exceeds your upper bound when $n\gg 1$.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I see your point that $P(T_\epsilon\le n)=1-\sqrt{n}e^{-\sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: How about if we change the initial distribution of $X_0$ to be uniformly distributed on the sphere with radius $\sqrt{n}$? In this case, $h(0)$ is a Gaussian of mean 0 and width 1. Then $|h(0)|\le \alpha$ with probability $\alpha$ for $0<\alpha<1$. So it seems that we can choose $\alpha=n^{-1/2}$?

Comment: a larger sphere will not help, the problem is that $h(0)$ can become very close to zero (by choosing the vector $X_0$ perpendicular to the vector $v_1$).

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a bit confused about why $n^{2/3}log n$ doesn't work.  In you answer, if we choose $\alpha=n^{-1/2}$, then $|h(0)|<n^{-1/2}$ with probability 1. So $T_\epsilon \le Cn^{2/3}\log n$ with probability 1. Can we conclude that $\lim_{n\to \infty} P(T_\epsilon\le C n^{2/3}\log n)=1$? For $P(T_\epsilon \le n)=1-\sqrt{n}e^{-\sqrt{n}}$, we will have $\lim_{n\to \infty} P(T_\epsilon\le Cn)=1$. I don't see where there is a contradiction?

Comment: it is not enough to have $|h(0)|<n^{-1/2}$ with probability $1$, to conclude that $T<n^{2/3}\log n$ with probability 1. You need a _lower_ bound on $h(0)$ not an _upper_ bound, because the smaller $h(0)$ is, the larger $T$ will be. And the Gaussian will not give you a lower bound...

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. Can you please see this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432647/the-lower-bound-for-the-hitting-time-of-ht. So the lower bound for $T_\epsilon$ should be fine?